# How to get popular friends from Facebook API?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I know I can get friends using https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends
I also know I can get friends by FQL like so:
    SELECT  uid,username
    FROM    user 
    WHERE   uid 
    IN (
        SELECT   uid2
        FROM     friend 
        WHERE    uid1 = me()
        LIMIT 20
    )
But what I need is to order these by the friends you interact with most often, i.e. your close friends.

Is this possible?

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to know who you message the most amongst your group of friends? Is this accurate?

Comment: yeah, that would be fair - or people you "like" the comments of, or who like yours etc.

Comment: as far as I know, this is impossible unless you try to store the relationship between EACH friend in a db and do your own algo to see who he/she interacts with the most

Comment: I suppose one way to do it would be to access https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed and see who liked your status or who posted things on your wall.

Comment: Took a brief look at this and executing in one query may not be practical since the select will be massive for someone with more than 50 friends. Since you're looking for the most popular person there would be no good way to limit the query's scope (friends). Large queries are likely to time out if they exceed the max execution time.

Answer (score 0):

you could search for the user's defined Lists.. The list "Close Friends" may contain such information though it is manually edited by the user himself (so it might be empty or not accurate)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to build an algorithm out for this yourself involving the several FQL queries (get likes, post comments, common photo tags, etc).